# Struct overight another value

Tags: c++

i'm trying to use structures in c++, but i faced into a problem :
I have a structure composed of an Name, and an Age :

```
struct Professeur {
        char* Name;
        int Age;
        Cours* ListeDeCours;
        Etudiant* ListeDEtudiant;
        Professeur* Suivant;
      };
```

When i try to put a Name, it works, and put an Age, it works to.
But if i pu a name then an Age, it overwrite the Name , see :

```
$ ./Doss 
Prof.Nom before the Age : Prof1
Prof.Age : 2
Prof.Nom after the Age : 2
end 2
```

Here is my code :

```
int i =0;
        string temp;
        Professeur prof;
        while(i != 4){
            if(i==0) {
                if(getline(fichier,temp)){
                    prof.Nom = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
                    prof.Nom = (char*) temp.c_str();
                    printf("Prof.Nom before the Age : %s\n",prof.Nom);

                    i++;
                }
            }
            if(i==1){
                if(getline(fichier,temp)){
                    prof.Ancien = atoi(temp.c_str());
                    printf("Prof.Age : %d\n",prof.Ancien);
                    printf("Prof.Nom after the Age : %s\n",prof.Nom);
                    i++;
                }
            }

        printf("end %s \n",prof.Nom);
        return prof;
    }
```

What did i miss? Seems that its a problem of pointer but idk why.
Thanks for your attention

Comment: It looks like you missed C++. C++ is not C, it's a totally different language.

Comment: i'm not sure to undestand what you're meaning, could you be more precise? Thanks

Comment: @n.m. It looks more like an attempt to write in non-existing, mythical "C/C++" because I can spot `string` and `getline` and `.c_str()`.

Comment: You are trying to use pointers and malloc. In C++ these things should almost never be used. You are not using them correctly, you guessed this part right, but that's irrelevant as you should not be using them at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prof.Nom = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));` allocates insufficient memory for the name (it only allocates enough bytes to fit a pointer). You then disregard that and set the name to point to the temporary string with `prof.Nom = (char*) temp.c_str();`. When you then executed `getline(fichier,temp)` again, the pointer to the raw string (obtained with `.c_str()`) happened to remain the same, meaning that name now points to the newly acquired string (because name still points to the same temporary string).

To fix easily, simply make name an `std::string` object.

Comment: Just, why does c_str() change my value? Not sure to undestand

Comment: Because you use the same string object (`temp`) to hold both values (both name and age). And you set name to point to the raw buffer of that string object.

Answer (score 1):

this is the point of the problem:

```
prof.Nom = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*));
prof.Nom = (char*) temp.c_str();
```

1. sizeof(char*) is a pointer size, not a char size, and the real size is depend on "getline(fichier,temp)".
2. you should use memcpy or strcpy to copy value to a memory space.(not just assign a reference, this is why your print "Prof.Nom after the Age : 2" happened, and 'Prof.Nom' is always 'temp').

so what we need is:

```
prof.Nom = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (temp.size() + 1));
strcpy(prof.Nom, temp.c_str());
```

in fact, it's better to use 'string' instead of 'char'. If you really want to use it in a struct, use 'char[MAX_LEN]' instead of 'char*' Because of annoying 'malloc' and 'free'.